# Issue using the function home_url() with an anchor

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am trying to use an anchor in the function `home_url()` of WordPress. The idea is simple: the user is browsing on the homepage, he clicks on the link and he is redirected to an anchor 'target' in the page 'cabinet-dentaire'.

When I write this code:

```
<a href="'esc_url( home_url( '/cabinet-dentaire/' ) )'">En savoir plus</a>
```

It is working great, and the user is redirected to `websitename/cabinet-dentaire/`

But when I'm writing this in order to add the anchor:

```
<a href="'esc_url( home_url( '/cabinet-dentaire/#target' ) )'">En savoir plus</a>
```

The result is `websitename/cabinet-dentaire/#target'))'`

I don't know why there is written `'))'` at the end as it normally comes from the code.

Comment: Thanks Kirk, it’s working. I am a bit less newbie in coding now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML lacks the required opening `<?php` and closing `?>` PHP tags, so the PHP functions in your code will not be processed correctly.

You should use the following code:

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/cabinet-dentaire' ) ); ?>#target">En savoir plus</a>
```

Some of the things that have been changed:

1. It includes the required `<?php ... ?>` opening/closing tags
2. It includes the `echo` required to print the values on screen. The `esc_url()` functions returns code rather than printing directly to screen
3. The `#target` shouldn't be put inside the `home_url()` function.
4. Removed the extra `'` apostrophes in the code.